# For each file in directory, use np.loadtxt?

Tags: python, directory

I'm looking to load each file in a directory using numpy.loadtxt or bumpy.genfromtxt.

```
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
        if filename.endswith(".hrt"):
                print filename
                Sin,Sout,IR = np.genfromtxt(filename,skip_header=11,usecols=(5,7,9),delimiter='  ', unpack = True)
```

The first part of this works (it correctly prints each filename in the directory that ends with ".hrt"). But then I'm not able to load the file into genfromtxt or loadtxt.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I also tried np.genfromtxt('{}'.format(filename),skip_header=11,usecols=(5,7,9),delimiter='  ', unpack = True)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this!

```
from glob import glob
for filename in glob("./*.hrt"):
      Sin,Sout,IR = np.genfromtxt(str(filename),skip_header=11,usecols=(5,7,9),delimiter='  ', unpack = True)
```